# how to get all the elements of an array using iterator in java?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have tried to take inputs in an array using Scanner, But there is something unusual happening, suppose , I am giving the inputs to the integer array as 1 2, when I am trying to print it is giving me 2 0. I am giving the code for further clarification

```
package org.prac.comp1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //int count=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        sc.next();
        String str=sc.nextLine();
        sc.next();
        int arr[]=new int[2];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(arr[i]);

        }
               }
    }
```

Input:

```
8
2
abcdabcd
1
2
```

output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the sc.next here.

`int n = sc.nextInt();
//sc.next();
String str = sc.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

`sc.next()` statement after the statement --> `String str=sc.nextLine();` still waits for the user to give string value. So `sc.next()` takes value of 1 and array elements start from 2. That is the reason its showing 2 instead of 1 :)